# Error message: plink: the -pw option can only be used with the SSH protocol

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I'm using the plink command to log in with SSH protocol.

```
plink -l UserName -pw password -t ServerAddress
```

but in one of our workstations I get the following error message:

**plink: the -pw option can only be used with the SSH protocol**

I guess that some setup parameter causes this message. If I add the -ssh option, then it prompts for the password.
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

okay a few sugegstions.

try adding the `-v` verbose switch and see if that give you more information.

for machine name.. do you have a putty profile saved with the same name? as "host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)  (see plink --help)

Comment: I added the -v option, but got the same message with no verbose info. I tried again today the -ssh switch and it worked fine without any prompts. But I still don't understand why I have to add it. SSH should be the default ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `plink` get it's default protocol from `putty`, and on my machine, the default settings is set to Serial.

Try loading the default settings in `putty`, change it SSH, and save it back.